# Solciitar permiso ermiso de camara Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

estoy intentando resolver un problema, mi App en xamarin necesita la cámara en una View. cuando se abre la App solicita los permisos(si el usuario concede los permisos, anda todo fantástico), si el usuario los rechaza, al entrar en la view pongo un botón para solicitar los permisos nuevamente, pero no funciona, No aparece el famosos cartel de android solicitando acceso.
y otra cosa extraña es que si cierro la App me aparece la solicitud de permisos nuevamente -solo se ve el mensaje de android solicitando permisos, mi app ya no se ve y esta cerrada-
Alguien me podrá orientar que puede estar pasando

Codigo del boton:

```
    private void BtnSolicitarAccesoCamara_OnClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            if (Plugin.Permissions.CrossPermissions.IsSupported)
            {
                var result = await Plugin.Permissions.CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Camera);

                if (result != Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted)

                {
                    var rp = await Plugin.Permissions.CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Camera);

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

MainActivity

```
 public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] global::Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in your Activity's OnCreate method:** "JMontemagno"

*Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);*

```
  private void BtnSolicitarAccesoCamara_OnClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {   
     try
        {
            var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                if(await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Camera))
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Need Camera", "Gunna need", "OK");
                }

                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Camera);
                //Best practice to always check that the key exists
                if(results.ContainsKey(Permission.Camera))
                    status = results[Permission.Camera];
            }

            else if(status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Camera Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Me soluiciono el problema